# Unable to access hivemq broker from raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, mqtt, hivemq

I want to use [hivemq](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/)
as an online broker for my IOT projects BUT the problem is I am unable to connect with hiveMQ from my raspberry pi. I am even unable to open hiveMQ website from my raspberry pi.

I tried subscribing to hiveMQ broker using this basic python script

---

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

MQTT_HOST = "broker.mqttdashboard.com"

MQTT_PORT = 1883

MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 5

MQTT_TOPIC = "testTopic"

def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc):
    mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC, 0)

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed to MOTT Topic...")

def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
    print(msg.payload)

mqttc = mqtt.Client()

mqttc.on_message = on_message

mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)

mqttc.loop_forever()
```

---

BUT IT IS THROWING AN ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "subscriber.py", line 23, in <module>
    mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 686, in connect
    return self.reconnect()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 808, in reconnect

    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))


File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 509, in create_connection
    raise err

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

---

on the other hand i also subscribed to my local MOSQUITTO broker using the same python script just by changing the HOST to the ip of my local machine and it was working fine...

Comment: The fact you can't reach the website and that you are getting `No route to host` errors implies you have more serious network issues than anything to do with MQTT specifically

Comment: @hardillb other than hivemq all other websites are reachable

Comment: Could also be related to DNS, can you try: broker.hivemq.com or broker.mqtt-dashboard.com ?

Comment: yes i tried that too didn't work. Isn't it some problem related to ports. I saw a blog where they ask to modify your ip table but not sure enough @DominikObermaier